# How to set color filter on ProgressBar in ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

I'm creating a default spinner progress dialog...

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Picture...");
pDialog.show();
```

But of course the spinner is the default color. **How would I change the color of this spinner?** I've changed the color of other spinners using...

```
    pb.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_red),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

But that only works when the spinner is in your layout. Not the case for the progress dialog I just generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color your code only..check below code

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            // Set progress dialog style spinner
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            // Set the progress dialog title and message
            pd.setTitle("Title of progress dialog.");
            pd.setMessage("Loading.........");

            // Set the progress dialog background color
            pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFD4D9D0")));

            pd.setIndeterminate(false);

            // Finally, show the progress dialog
            pd.show();
```

For Spinner you can use Drawable XMl like this

XML

```
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="8"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="76dip"
        android:width="76dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#00FF00"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

And set this to your Progress Dialog like this

pd.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_xml));

Comment: I specifically asked how to change the color of the spinner, not the background.

Comment: Hmm interesting. It didn't spin though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the ProgressDialog with the specific style just like below.

```
 proDia= new ProgressDialog(TakeActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
    proDia.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.searching));
```

style

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/main_green</item>
<item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@color/main_green</item>
```

Just set the colorAccent to your color,and it will work.

And this is the result by the style:

[image: And this is the result by the style]